# Exec /usr/bin/latex

Tags: php, latex, exec

When I try the following PHP code:
`exec('/usr/bin/latex ...')`
I'll get an 127-exit code. What can I do to stop this?

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: What are the rest of the arguments?

Comment: `'/usr/bin/latex --interaction=nonstopmode ' . $texFile`

Comment: What is the output of the command? It should describe the problem you're having.

Comment: Try rerouting the output so php can see it, you might get a better error message: exec('/usr/bin/latex --interaction=nonstopmode ' . $texFile . ' 2>&1', $output); print_r($output);

Comment: Nothing, I did exec('..', $a, $b) and those variables contains 127 and Array() (empty) after executing.

Answer (score 2):

127 error code indicates the command was not found by bash. You sure that latex is installed?

Comment: Yes, when I echo the code and execute it manually (as root), it can be executed.

Comment: @Kevin, what are the permissions on /usr/bin/latex ?  does www-data user or whomever your apache instance runs as have permission to execute?

Comment: 0777, www-data, I guess so, because it's 0777?

Comment: I would be very worried about an executable that is writable for everyone.  Oh wait, perhaps it is a symbolic link, and the real file has different permissions?

Answer (score -2):

Why do not use ssh2 ?

something like this:

```
//Connect first
if (!($con = @ssh2_connect('192.168.0.1', 22))) {

    echo "[FAILED_CONNECT]\n";
    exit(1);

}

if (!@ssh2_auth_password($con, "your_user", "your_password")) {

    echo "[FAILED_AUTH_DENIED]\n";
    exit(1);

}
echo "[OK]\n CONNECTED!";


// the command line
$stdout_stream = ssh2_exec($con, "/usr/bin/latex ...");


// close connection
fclose($stdout_stream);
```

Comment: Why would you want to use ssh to connect to localhost?

Comment: @SVICK WHERE DOES IT SAYS LOCALHOST???? READ FIRST DOWN VOTE AFTER, BUT IF DO NOT UNDERSTAND THE POINT DO NOT GIVE DOWN VOTE TO ANYONE.. GREAT!

Comment: `exec()` executes code on the current computer, so it implicitly says localhost. No need to scream.

Comment: 192.* is localhost ;). Besides, your caps lock is on.

Comment: @KEvin Er...192.168.*.* are the local class C networks, but not necessarily localhost. Now, 127.*.*.* is localhost.

Comment: Every body sorry about capslock ON, I was trying to help, the follow code works perfect to me, even if is local or not.. just a little help. You have e few possibilities to interpret the question of our mate @kevin. No problem at all.